# Trying to access FOR loop variables within inner class, it is a scope question

Tags: android

First of all thanks for taking time to look at my question

I have an array of editText and an array of doubles, I have a listener for the editText, whenever I enter a new value into the editText I would like to update the value in the double array

So I thought I could use a for loop to scan through all the editText and in each iteration, it would update the elements in the double array,

right now I have the code as follows

however, in the method "public void onTextChanged" when I try to use x from the "FOR" loop it is giving me an error saying that x in accessed within inner class and must be declared final, but I do not want x to be final, can somebody help me find a way to do this?

In other posts people suggested setting x as global variable, and maybe in the for loop when x reaches a certain value reset it to 0?

Thank you in advance

```
public class Test1 extends AppCompatActivity {
//In Test1 activity scope 
    EditText editText1;
    EditText EditText2;
    EditText EditText3;
    String Results;
//I have my double array 
   double doubleArray[] = new double[] {
            0.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
    };    
//declare the doubles that will be assigned in the double array
    double double1 = 0.0;
    double double2 = 0.0;
    double double3 = 0.0;
/*My editText array, here is where I'm struggling, 
I don't know how and where to create an editText array, 
or if I'm using the correct syntax, also I feel that 
editText1,2,and 3 should not be initialized here*/
EditText[] editTextArray = new EditText[] {
            (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1),
            (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2),
            (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3),
};
//In the onCreate method
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Test1);
    for (int x = 0; x < editTextArray.length; x++) {
            editTextArray[x].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    try {
                        Results = editTextArray[x].getText().toString();
                        if (Results.equals("")) {
                            Results = "0.0" ;
                            doubleArray[x] = Double.parseDouble(Results);
                        }
                        else {
                            doubleArray[x] = Double.parseDouble(Results);
                        }
                        LetsFillTheVariables();
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException e){}
                }
            });
    }

    private void LetsFillTheVariables() {
        double1 = doubleArray[0];
        double2 = doubleArray[1];
        double3 = doubleArray[2];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary final variable:

```java
for (int x = 0; x < editTextArray.length; x++) {
    final int idx = x;
    editTextArray[idx].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try {
                Results = editTextArray[idx].getText().toString();
                if (Results.equals("")) {
                    Results = "0.0" ;
                    doubleArray[idx] = Double.parseDouble(Results);
                }
                else {
                    doubleArray[idx] = Double.parseDouble(Results);
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, theshyelf, I think it will work, but I may have a bigger problem on this subject, I will edit my code in the post